ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash_bio'
I am attempting to emulate the first example (under IGV) from the following website into my own code. To do that, I copied the sample code into a file and ran it in the windows terminal.
I am getting the error displayed in the image which is
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash_bio' ".
I appreciate your help!
Reference below:
https://dash.plotly.com/dash-bio/igv  (The code is also copied below)
import json
import urllib.request as urlreq
from dash import Dash, html, Input, Output, callback
import dash_bio as dashbio

app = Dash(__name__)


model_data = urlreq.urlopen(
    'https://git.io/mol2d_buckminsterfullerene.json'
).read().decode('utf-8')

model_data = json.loads(model_data)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dashbio.Molecule2dViewer(
        id='dashbio-default-molecule2d',
        modelData=model_data
    ),
    html.Hr(),
    html.Div(id='default-molecule2d-output')
])

@callback(
    Output('default-molecule2d-output', 'children'),
    Input('dashbio-default-molecule2d', 'selectedAtomIds')
)
def update_selected_atoms(ids):
    if ids is None or len(ids) == 0:
        return "No atom has been selected. Select atoms by clicking on them."
    return "Selected atom IDs: {}.".format(', '.join([str(i) for i in ids]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

To fix the issue, I have re-installed dash bio (pip install dash-bio==1.0.1) , renamed the file, and tried altering the wording of dash bio in the event of a syntax error. Can someone please guide me in fixing this issue?
pip show dash-bio -->
This command shows the following output:

import sys; print(sys.path) -->
This command shows the following output:

Update --> Dash-bio was not installed. During installation, I received this error:
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for parmed
Failed to build parmed
ERROR: Could not build wheels for parmed, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have re-installed dash bio Show us the exact command you used to install the dash-bio module.

pip install dash-bio==1.0.1

Now show us the output of this command pip show dash-bio and also the output of this code import sys; print(sys.path) Please include those in the question, not as a comment.

Please include those outputs in the question as plain text.  Don't make us read images.  And the import was to be executed as code, not as a command.
